# %precision 2 on Python

Tags: python, precision

If I have this piece of code:

```
import csv

%precision 2

with open('blah.csv') as csvfile:
    blah = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))
```

What does it means the `%precision 2` line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an IPython magic. It controls how floats display:

```
>>> 1.2345
1.2345
>>> %precision 2
'%.2f'
>>> 1.2345
1.23
```

Documented [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-precision).

*Note*: It suggests your script was intended to be executed within an IPython runtime (such as a [notebook](http://jupyter.org/)). In a regular Python interpreter that will be a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm learning Python and using, indeed, Jupyter notebook. The documentation link you gave helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This is to set a floating point precision for printing. It sets the floating point to 2 decimal points. This doesn't work in all interpreters though, but it does work in Jupyter-Notebook.

NB: Thanks to Chrisz for the point.

Comment: This is sort of correct, but this won't work in the standard python interpreter.  You  may want to clarify.

Comment: More generally, it works in an `IPython` interpreter.