# SyntaxError: invalid syntax - %pylab

Tags: python, python-3.x

Unfortunately I am not a programmer and I am encountering the error:

```
$ python3 code.py
   File "code.py", line 7
     % pylab inline
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The original code is on that [link](https://github.com/anurag-code/Survival-Analysis-Intuition-Implementation-in-Python/blob/master/Survival%20Analysis%20-%20Quick%20Implementation.ipynb) and is the first part. I'm not using Junyper.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: the % pylab inline is a [jupyter magic method](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pylab). If you're not using jupyter, then you need to leave that out

Comment: is there no way to run without being in Junyper?

Comment: related: [%precision 2 on Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50375504/674039)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`%pylab`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pylab) is an IPython magic for [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/). It's equivalent to this:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pylab, mlab, pyplot
np = numpy
plt = pyplot

from IPython.display import display
from IPython.core.pylabtools import figsize, getfigs

from pylab import *
from numpy import *
```

The positional argument `inline` is specifying a matplotlib backend. Supported choices here depend on your platform and runtime (see `matplotlib.rcsetup.all_backends` for options).

If you're not using Jupyter notebooks, you can do the same in an IPython session. You'll need to have installed `matplotlib` in your Python environment.

Comment: Yes, I was. I tried to execute your suggestion, but the same error happens...

Comment: It will run in **IPython**. It will not run in regular python unless you remove/replace the magic.

Comment: As I said I'm not a programmer, I'm trying to use the code created to analyze data... I run the program in the Ubuntu terminal using the command: python3 code.py

Comment: You can use `python3 -m IPython code.py`. Or just use jupyter notebooks. Or replace the magics in the source code. Up to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You should run the program in Jupyter, or at least IPython. The `%` is IPython-specific syntax, and [`pylab`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pylab) is an IPython magic command for using matplotlib. Also note the file extension: .ipynb is a Jupyter notebook (formerly called **IPy**thon **n**ote**b**ook), while a Python file would have a .py extension.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there no way to run without being in Junyper?

Comment: It is not a Jupyter-specific extension. It is for matplotlib.

Comment: @Marcelo *Jupyter. And I'm not really sure since I don't use Jupyter myself.

Comment: @wim Thanks. How would you run matplotlib outside of Jupyter? Like if you ran it in IPython, would it open a popup with the image?

Comment: @wjandrea It would open a popup usually, yes. That is depending on the matplotlib backend that is configured, though.

Comment: Yes, Jupyter*. Ok, nop.

Comment: @wim Thanks! Edited to add.

Comment: @Marcelo You would need to run it in IPython at least. I edited to add.

Comment: @wjandrea See screenshot in [Turning a Large Matrix into a Grayscale Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7696336/674039) for an example of what IPython using inline backend looks like (no popup). I think that was Qt4Agg backend (but it was some years ago and I don't use inline backend anymore).